# numpy custom dtype challenge

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, complex-numbers

I have an array of custom dtype *my_type* which I successfully read from a binary file. The custom dtype has a header section after that comes the data. The data part are **np.int16** numbers, so the custom dtype looks like this:

```
header, imaginary, real, imaginary, real,  ..., imaginary, real
```

Now I am looking for a smart way to use Numpy's **view** to get an array of **np.complex64** of *only data* without copying/looping etc. considering the following facts:

- the header part should be ignored
- somehow correct the order (i.e. first real, imaginary)
- the resulting array should be complex64 not complex32!

That is, from an array of custom dtype:

```
[my_type, my_type, ..., my_type]
```

I like to get a much larger array containing:

```
[complex64, complex64, ..., complex64]
```

Is it possible to do this in one go using Numpy's **view**?

**UPDATE:**

So the solution is copying in memory. Many thanks to the answers below. But because the annoying header appears before every data frame, it seems that in spite of copying in the memory, a loop over all data frames is still necessary. In a schematic manner I have:

```
a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float16)
skip_annoying_header = 2
r = np.zeros(a.size - skip_annoying_header, np.float16)
r[0::2], r[1::2] = a[skip_annoying_header + 1::2], a[skip_annoying_header::2]
r = r.astype(np.float32)
r = r.view(np.complex64)
```

And I do this in a `for` loop for every data frame, and then at the end of the `for` loop, I copy again the content of `r` into **big** array.

Can this looping be somehow eliminated?

Comment: It's hard to tell when you are talking about data on the file, and the array that you've loaded.  Transforming your data as you read it one 'dataframe' at a time from the file is one thing, transforming a structured array is another.  If you already have the array show it's `dtype` and `shape`.

Answer (score 3):

All 3 requirements conflict with a `view`.

Ignoring the `header` field requires selecting the other fields.  Selecting a single field is clearly a view, but the state of multiple fields is in flux.  When I try anything besides simply viewing the values I get a warning:

```
In [497]: dt=np.dtype('U10,f,f,f,f')
In [498]: x=np.zeros((5,),dt)

In [505]: x[['f1','f3']].__array_interface__
/usr/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a record
array. This code will likely break in a future numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
```

Remember, the data is layed out element by element, with the dtype tuple values in compact blocks - essentially a compact version of the display.  Ignoring the `header` requires skipping that set of bytes.  `view` can handle skips produced by `strides`, but not these dtype field skips.

```
In [533]: x
Out[533]: 
array([('header', 0.0, 5.0, 1.0, 10.0), ('header', 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 10.0),
       ('header', 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 10.0), ('header', 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 10.0),
       ('header', 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4')])
```

To explore reordering the complex fields, lets try a 2d array:

```
In [509]: y=np.arange(10.).reshape(5,2)  # 2 column float
In [510]: y.view(complex)    # can be viewed as complex
Out[510]: 
array([[ 0.+1.j],
       [ 2.+3.j],
       [ 4.+5.j],
       [ 6.+7.j],
       [ 8.+9.j]])
In [511]: y[:,::-1].view(complex)
...
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

To switch the real/imaginay columns I have to make a copy.  `complex` requires that the 2 floats be contiguous and in order.

```
In [512]: y[:,::-1].copy().view(complex)
Out[512]: 
array([[ 1.+0.j],
       [ 3.+2.j],
       [ 5.+4.j],
       [ 7.+6.j],
       [ 9.+8.j]])
```

`float32` to `float64` is clearly not a `view` change.  One uses 4 bytes per number, the other 8.  You can't 'view' 4 as 8 without copying.

Comment: This is nice. I didn't know about the requirement for contiguous data. I wonder how much does copying "cost" in terms of speed...

Comment: @xaratustra. Not much. In fact, it generally pays to copy large datasets into the best order before processing.

Comment: Now (1.19+) a multifield index produces a `view`, the original dtype with fields 'blanked out'.  There's a `repack` function if you need a contiguous array (e.g. for viewing as complex).

Answer (score 2):

@hpaulj is absolutely correct that this conflicts with a view.

However, you may be asking the wrong question.

`numpy` can certainly do what you're wanting to do but you'll need to make a temporary copy in memory.

Overall, you're probably better served by rethinking the "read the entire file into memory and then view it" approach.  Instead seek past (or read in) the header, then read in the data portion with `fromfile`.  After than, it's relatively straightforward to manipulate things into what you want, as long as you don't mind making a copy to go from `float32`'s to `float64`'s.

---

To start out with, let's generate a file similar to yours:

```
import numpy as np

reals = np.arange(100).astype(np.float32)
imag = -9999.0 * np.ones(100).astype(np.float32)

data = np.empty(reals.size + imag.size, dtype=np.float32)
data[::2], data[1::2] = imag, reals

with open('temp.dat', 'wb') as outfile:
    # Write a 1Kb header (of literal "x"'s, in this case)
    outfile.write(1024 * 'x')
    outfile.write(data)
```

Now we'll read it in.

The key to ignoring the header is to `seek` past it before reading the data in with `fromfile`.

Then, we can de-interleave the data and convert to 64-bit floats at the same time.

Finally, you can then view the resulting 2xN-length `float64` array as an N-length `complex128` array.  (Note: `complex128` is the 64-bit version of a complex number. `complex64` is the 32-bit version.)

For example:

```
import numpy as np

with open('temp.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    # Seek past header
    infile.seek(1024)

    # Read in rest of file as float32's
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype=np.float32)

result = np.empty(data.size, np.float64)

# De-interleave imag & real back into expected real & imag, converting to 64-bit
result[::2], result[1::2] = data[1::2], data[::2]

# View the result as complex128's (i.e. 64-bit complex numbers)
result = result.view(np.complex128)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Indeed I am using `seek` because the files are usually huge, can get up to 2GB each. But the problem is that the annoying header appears before every data frame, so it seems that the loop is necessary....